# How to SSH using ssh keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen, authorized-keys

We've recently set up a new Linux box which is on the same local network as the rest of our machines. We want to allow only the machines on the local network to be able to SSH into the new machine, and I was going to do this by creating ssh keys and disabling password authentication.

What I've done is run `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` on the new machine, copy the contents of the public key and put this in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on one of the machines previously set up.

I've then gone into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the new machine and have this:

```
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Those are the only changes I made to this file, and when I try to SSH from the old machine, I get `"Permission denied(publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"`

If I enable `PasswordAuthentication` and try to ssh I can log in by entering the user's password, but that's not the goal.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se], [sf], or [su].

Answer (score 0):

If the user you are trying to log in as is `root`, the directive

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

is denying access, regardless the authentication method.
To allow root to log in using keys only, you should set this directive to `prohibit-password`